# Get an element with mousemove

Tags: jquery, mousemove

Is it possible to get the current element using mousemove ? I'd like to get the element where the mouse is to do specifics things if the mouse isn't on an element x or y.

For exemple :

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e)
    {
        if(e.xxxx.attr("id") == "elem")
            ...
    });
```

xxxx is what I'm looking for, and I hope it exists :)

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you mean the element the mouse is over, yes, it's available as the [`target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) property of the event object.

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e)
{
    if (e.target.id == "elem") {
        // ...
    }
});
```

`target` is a DOM element, and you can access the `id` of the element directly from its `id` property (a reflected property that takes its value from the attribute). If you wanted to do other things with it and wanted access to the jQuery functions, you'd use `$(e.target)` to get a jQuery wrapper for it.

Comment: Tanks four the answer. I thought the target property was only for mouseenter/mouseleave events.

Comment: @thomash: Nope, any element-generated event has it (and nearly all events are element-generated). :-)

Comment: I checked the answer. Thanks for your help ;)